# Value to controller from action link is always null

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Have a view that just takes a string

```
@model string
```

Calling from ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Clinical Desktop", "Training", "Video"
    , new { play = "SomeVideo.mp4" }, null)
```

VideoController

```
public ActionResult Training(string play)
{
    return View(play);
}
```

`play` is always null

Calling URL manually

```
https://localhost:44300/Video/Training/play?SomeVideo.mp4
```

Comment: Try https://localhost:44300/Video/Training/?play=SomeVideo.mp4

Comment: AFAIK you need to make sure your parameters are named in your routes, for example with a {controller}/{action}/{id} route  will try to assign a parameter named "id"

Comment: @Tsukasa Could you please provide Route configuration then we will decide where the issue.